# How to increase the size of an image in 6 column class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I am unable to stretch the image to full width till right corner. it should be responsive. My code is integrated in wordpress. You can see the image in class membershipImgBox. So How can I increase the size of my image.

The code as follows.

```css
.membershipbox {
  height: 100%;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- for icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
</head>
<section class="deliveringSection ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 img-box-2" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
        <div id="img-2" class="membershipImgBox">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/987/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/" class="img-fluid d-block mb-5 mb-lg-0 mx-auto" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 order-lg-first" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
        <div class="deliveringContent">
          <div class="sectionHeading" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
            <h2>
              Delivering quality projects to
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionHeadingTwo" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
            <h2><b>World Class </b></h2>
            <h2>Standards</h2>
            <div class="about-border"></div>
          </div>
          <p>We work around three important elements of our business to create world-class innovative interior design solutions to meet our clients’ functional & aesthetic requirements providing unique tailored space solutions. We integrate the client’s
            brand and business strategy, placing great emphasis on the brand’s values and aspirations to bring projects to fruition, taking our strong working relationship to the next level..​​</p>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnWeight"> about us </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and post RENDERED HTML without the PHP. You can find an image at placeholder.com

Comment: it's done. You can check

Comment: Not done. I made you a snippet. The HTML is invalid and there is no image or bootstrap files

Comment: I want image 987 x 612 .

Comment: Please help. its in one row.

Comment: The HTML is still not valid. Iff you edit, then scroll  down and edit above snippet, you will see the P and the `</div>
  </div>
</section>` are red. Also 100% is 100% of the parent container. What 100% do you mean? Viewport?

Answer (score 0):

because it is inside a container class which have max-width and some margin so your image will not go outside it's container

you could put the image outside container and it will stretch to the edges of the page

```css
.membershipbox {
  height: 100%;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <!-- for icons -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
    </head>
<section class="deliveringSection ">
<div id="img-2" class="membershipImgBox">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/987x612" class="img-fluid d-block mb-5 mb-lg-0 mx-auto" alt="" />
        </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 img-box-2" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
        
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 order-lg-first" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
        <div class="deliveringContent">
          <div class="sectionHeading" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
            <h2>
              Delivering quality projects to
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionHeadingTwo" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="2000">
            <h2><b>World Class </b></h2>
            <h2>Standards</h2>
            <div class="about-border"></div>
          </div>
          <p>We work​​</p>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnWeight"> about us </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```